# What is the defining difference between a compiler and a preprocessor?

Tags: compilation

I got the following question in which the correct answer is B. I don't understand why A is not correct, because the compiler is doing optimization on the code and I didn't find any information about a preproccessor that is doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the right answer is B ;)

A compiler doesn't have to make code improvement to produce correct machine code. it's main task is to produce machine code from source code by performing syntactic and semantic analysis on source code and the if the code is OK produce machine code.

A compiler can produce correct machine code without optimization

In gcc for example you can choose optimization level with option -O

Comment: but if he find that he need to perform an optimization? he can do that no?

Comment: this is from wikipedia: "A compiler is likely to perform many or all of the following operations: lexical analysis, preprocessing, parsing, semantic analysis (syntax-directed translation), code generation, and code optimization"

Comment: yes sure it can do !! but it's not it's main purpose. A non optimized code can work well also (maybe slower but correct). And wikipedia says "many or all so optimization can be exclude :)

Comment: so in this case solution a should be also correct because that answer says exactly what you said above.

Comment: at school we create a simple compiler that work and doesn't perfoms code improvement so how do you call such a compiler. Produce machine code from souce code is MUST and SHOULD do optimization

Answer (score 0):

A compiler takes source code written in a programming language and converts it into machine code that can be run on a computer. A preprocessor is a program that processes a source code file before it is passed to the compiler.